# Test for background-blend-mode support that correctly targets iOS Safari and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, background-blend-mode

I am having a frustrating issue with using CSS background-blend-mode in a way that gracefully degrades everywhere; specifically, Safari and Chrome on iOS seem to evade my efforts to test them for support.

As of this writing, background-blend-mode (at least in basic form) is supported in the latest version of most browsers except IE (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode). I am using it to blend a solid background color with a grayscale texture, like so:

```
.banner-inner {
    background-image: url("../img/banner-bg-texture.png");
    background-color: #7692b4;
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

Background-blend-mode is designed to degrade so that if it's not supported in a browser, that browser just sees the normal background-image. However, I want to specifically target those unsupporting browsers so that they only see the ***solid color***, like so:

```
.no-background-blend-mode .banner-inner {
    background: #7692b4; // If no blend-mode support, fall back to solid color
}
```

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) and others suggest a JavaScript-based test for support of this property, which I'm using like so:

```
// Test for background-blend-mode support
    ;(function(window) {

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var supportsBackgroundBlendMode = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundBlendMode;

            if(typeof supportsBackgroundBlendMode === "undefined") {  
                document.documentElement.className += " no-background-blend-mode";
            }
        }, false);

    })(window);
```

This works fine for targeting IE, which gets the proper .no-background-blend-mode class. Chrome, Firefox and Safari on desktop all support the blend-mode just fine.

**Here's the problem:** I'm looking at both Safari and Chrome on iOS 8.3, and they both ***pass the test*** (`typeof supportsBackgroundBlendMode` returns "normal") but ***fail to implement the blend mode.*** (They both show the grayscale background-image alone, rather than a blend).

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here, and/or help me find a way to test & target these browsers for this feature, that actually works? Thank you!

**Update:** Still haven't found a good solution for this issue, which persists into iOS 8.4.1 (most current as of this edit).

Comment: "Can anyone help me understand what's going on here" Simple: WebKit-based browsers are known to lie about their support for various features. This is why, unfortunately, feature detection isn't the silver bullet it's made out to be.